# C program output should go to console, but should not be redirectable

Tags: c, linux

I want `my_custom_print()` output to appear on console. But if the program's `stderror` or `stdout` is redirected from `shell`, they should get redirected (as normal), but the output from `my_custom_print()` should get ignored.

Is it possible to write `my_custom_print()` satisfying above condition ? If possible, how?

Comment: But I'm not sure it is worth the effort. E.g. a user could copy & past e from a terminal, etc.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: One common use-case I know where this is wanted is a password prompt, like `ssh` is doing. Try `ssh user@host command &>somefile`, you will still get a password prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try opening `/dev/tty`, but it doesn't necessarily exist, if your program run from the environment with no tty.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [isatty](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) or [/dev/tty](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty) could be useful to you.